# Setup GitLab CI for Rails with npm

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

These days I am struggling with GitLab CI setup for my project. The setup is not as simple as Travis CI. I've spent a whole lot of time debugging this and all I found do not fit my requirements

## Context

I have a Rails project which is using `rvm` and `npm` and `postgresql`. I built a custom Docker image with `rvm` and `npm` installed. However, before running I have to get the correspond `ruby` and `node` version as in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
image: "my-rvm-npm-image"

services:
  - postgres:9.3-alpine

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: db
  POSTGRES_USER: user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD:

cache:
  untracked: true
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - build
  - rspec
  - npm

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - sudo chown -R $(whoami) /cache
    - /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install $(cat .ruby-version)
      && rvm use $(cat .ruby-version)
      && gem install bundle && bundle install --jobs $(nproc) --path /cache
      && source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install && npm install npm -g && npm install
      && bundle exec rake db:test:prepare"

rspec:
  stage: rspec
  script:
    - bundle exec rake
npm:
  stage: npm
  script:
    - npm test
```

Please note that this `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is still `failed`. `bundle install` will be in the `/cache` as in GitLab runner configuration:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "xxxx"
  url = "URLabc.com"
  token = "myprojectoken"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "my-rvm-npm-image"
    privileged = true 
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/home/ci/cache:/cache", "/home/ci/builds:/builds"]
  [runners.cache]
```

`builds` and `cache` folder are host-bound. So that I can keep the `bundle install` cache for the next build.

## My problem

`build` job passes, but `rspec` and `npm` failed `/bin/bash: bundle: command not found`. It seems that the `bundle` is not passed to other jobs. I know I should use `artifacts` to pass to other job, but I already have it as cache, I should have

I want to achieve these goals:

- Cache `bundle install` for every run, since it take 10 ~ 15 mins to rebuild from scratch, and pass to `rspec` job to run the test.
- Also cache `node_modules` from `npm install` and pass to `npm` job.
- Any suggestion for `rvm` and `npm` installation, because I do not want the ugly way `bash -l -c` before every command.

Comment: "The cache is provided on a best-effort basis, so don't expect that the cache will be always present."